# Reflected Brownian Motion with random barrier?

Tags: brownian-motion

I am looking for a way to say something about
$$P\left(\max_{t\in[0,n]} W_t+|W_m|> x\right),$$
for $n>m$, where $W$ is a brownian motion with drift.